# Give all users of a group ability to rm, cp, mv, edit, etc files into or out of a directory

Tags: linux, bash, privileges, gitlab, ownership

so I've created a directory that will be used across multiple users at `/SharedDir`. This shared directory is currently configured as such.

```
drwxrwsrwx+ 6 root group 4.0K Mar 23 20:40 /SharedDir
```

No files are being created directly within this directory. I'm using `Gitlab-runner` and a CI/CD script to generate documents and transfer them into this directory for review by users at a later time.The build script generates both files, and files within other folders.

```
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 gitlab-runner group 3.5K Mar 23 21:07 data.html
drwxrwsr-x+ 2 gitlab-runner group 4.0K Mar 23 21:07 _directory
```

With `Gitlab-runner` I'm able to run the scripts and transfer what I need into the shared directory. `Gitlab-runner` doesn't need elevated privileges to move these files/folders into the shared directory.

However, a user like myself needs elevated privileges in order to delete any of these files/folders. As well if I run the scripts manually, outside of `Gitlab-runner`, I again need elevated privileges to move them into the shared directory.

What I've done:

created group

```
groupadd group
```

added all users to the group

```
usermod -a -G group user1 user2 user3 gitlab-runner
```

change group for directory

```
chgrp group /SharedDir
```

I also set the permission for /SharedDir recursively

```
chown -R mainUser:group /SharedDir    
chmod -R a+wr /SharedDir
```

What works:

As a user, I can generate files/folders and move files/folders into `SharedDir` without `sudo`. When I run `Gitlab-runner` its able to delete files/folders generated by any user without the use of `sudo', and add new files/folders to the` SharedDir`

what doesn't work

Any files folders that were generated by `Gitlab-runner` other users can not delete without using `sudo`.

Comment: is execute on for owner/group/other on the directory directly containing the files you are having trouble deleting?

Comment: @FrankThomas, I'm sorry. I'm having a hard time understanding what your asking. Currently, with the above `Gitlab-runner` has no issues deleting or moving files/folders into /SharedDir. However, all other users require the use of Sudo to make modifications to /SharedDir. I don't understand why, or how I can remove sudo requirment.

Comment: Per this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622606/what-permissions-are-needed-to-delete-a-file-in-unix the user deleting the file needs write on the file, but also write and execute on the directory containing the file. you said that files are not created in the shareddir, so they must be in a subdirectory of it. check the users permissions on the directory immediately containing the file (the subdirectory). setgid fixes ownership so that the group-owner is always the group that owns shareddir, but it doesn't do anything about permissions on subdirs or files.

Comment: is shareddir accessed via SAMBA/SMB? if so, you can set a create mask on the share, to set the permissions to a default value